# Why can't I tell that `I<class> is I<abstract base class>`?

Tags: .net, inheritance, casting

I've got this setup in my code:

```
public abstract class ModelBase{}
public interface IModelbase<T>{}
public abstract class ModelBase<T> : ModelBase, IModelBase<T> {}
public class MyClass : ModelBase<int> {}
```

And then later I'm given a `FutureValue<MyClass>` object by NHibernate, and I try to:

```
if (obj is IFutureValue<ModelBase>) // => false?
// or
if (obj is FutureValue<ModelBase>) // => false?
// (I changed NHibernate's source to make FutureValue public, for other uses)
```

Meanwhile, if I cast it to the type directly:

```
if (((IFutureValue<MyClass>)obj).Value is ModelBase) // => true!
// or
if (((FutureValue<MyClass>)obj).Value is ModelBase) // => true!
```

... seriously?  It's in the inheritance chain, is there some reason it isn't looking up it?  Inspecting the object in the debugger shows it is in fact MyClass, and does have ModelBase methods and properties on it, so I doubt it has anything to do with NHibernate's proxying.

Why would .NET not look up the inheritance chains in such a situation?  Is there some keyword / casting trick I can perform to get it to do so?  Or do I have to resort to a large, clunky setup similar to:

```
if (obj is IFutureValue<MyClass>) return ((IFutureValue<MyClass>)obj).Value;
if (obj is IFutureValue<MyOtherClass>) return ((IFutureValue<MyOtherClass>)obj).Value;
// etc etc ad infinitum
```

edit: this is in .NET 2.0

---

edit2: the exact code of (I)FutureValue:

```
public interface IFutureValue<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}
public class FutureValue<T> : IFutureValue<T>
{
    public delegate IList<T> GetResult();

    private readonly GetResult getResult;

    public FutureValue(GetResult result)
    {
        getResult = result;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            var result = getResult();

            if (result.Count == 0)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            return result[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Am I just hugely misunderstanding the covariance / contravariance issue (in which case, why can `Func<Type2, Type2> f1 = MyMethod;` be cast to `Func<Type3, Type1> f2 = f1;` (where the first type is the return type) but the above code cannot do the same?  Unless it's just .NET 2.0 being lame with polymorphism?

---

edit3: thinking while typing.  Is this case because `IList<T>` defines delegates which take, say, Derived type, therefore need Derived or DoublyDerived T, but the return type can only be T or Base?  So I can't cast either direction... I wonder if I can convince NHibernate to switch to `IEnumerable<T>` in their Futures... would that solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IFutureValue<T>` is a generic interface with a **Covariant** Type-parameter.  You seem to be expecting the behavior of a **Contravariant** generic type parameter.  [For more information, read the MSDN documentation on **Covariance and Contravariance in Generics**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: Is it because FutureValue<T> *uses* a contravariant delegate internally, to get Value?

Nice link, hadn't thought of it that way.  Seems natural though, as delegates for derived types are passed to things which expect their base types.

- So where does this leave me?  Specifying everything as the most-precise types?

Comment: And it seems like you have your terminology backwards... I'm expecting covariant, which matches precisely the covariant example in your link, while it's behaving like a contravariant (so I could perhaps cast it to a further-derived type, but not my base type).

Comment: And this is .NET 2.0 (just added to the question).  Does this mean that *no* generics are covariant prior to 4.0?  I don't think I've ever tried casting things in collections in the "opposite" direction before...

Comment: No, that still doesn't make sense.  Looking more closely at the IFutureValue / FutureValue setup (added code to question), it's all return types, no parameters... the only delegate returns IList<T> and takes no parameters.  All along the way, it's just returned values, which can be cast to base-classes, as it makes sense and is confirmed by that article.  Unless .NET 2 can't do it at all, of course - then that's just a royal pain.

Comment: More thinking!  And apologies that you're subject to all this, it's a new term / issue I hadn't thought of before, so I'm redefining my thoughts a bit.  I just added "edit3", mind telling me if I got that right?  Which would make FutureValue<T> completely non-variant, which sucks.